# SQL, extract integer before and after '-' of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a column with these values

```
row 1 Spare Part ##:      **704604-001** part 
row 2 Spare Part #:   **511778-001** 
row 3 part number, a list of common parts follows...**439730-001**)Part number Description   

row 4 Spare Part:     **774172-001**&#x0D;Memory Board Nu
row 5 Spare Part:**639852-001**
```

I want to extract only the xxxxxx-001 out of the string.
example result:

```
704604-001
511778-001
439730-001
774172-001
```

Anyone can help me?

SQL 2012

Comment: REGEXP will work for you.

Comment: Which. RDBMS. Are. You. Using.

Comment: Use `split_part()` or `string_to_array()`

Comment: Help us help you, tell us which dbms you're using!

Comment: I am using SQL 2012

Comment: Always 6 digits before and 3 after?

Comment: yes @jarlh thats correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the values ​​of wanted expressions are always equal:

```
declare @row nvarchar(500)
set @row = 'row 1 Spare Part ##:      **704604-001** part'

select substring(@row,CHARINDEX('-',@row)-6,10)
```

return:

```
704604-001
```

Comment: I couldn't vote up because of just joined this site.

Comment: wow, he solved your problem, simply because he used the precise function names that work with your RDBMS, which you were keeping a secret for about 20 minutes.  Nice.

Comment: @Mike any way OP got solution by this answer